# Hide sidenav when routing to child component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngxs

I have a home component with toolbar and sidenav (Angular Material design). I have three dropdowns on sidenav:
1. Country
2. State
3. City
On selecting the city I route to nested child component and want to hide the sidenav also:

home.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

home.component.ts

```
  selectCity(event) {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetCityDetails(event.value))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.isHome = false;
        this._route.navigate(['home/citydetail']);
      });
  }
```

I use *ngIf to hide or show the sidenav.

The problem I'm facing is that if I set "isHome = false" then I don't get any error but angular doesn't load the citydetail component.

If I don't hide the sidenav then component loads up alright. I'm not sure what the issue is because I'm not getting any error also.

Please suggest the best way to hide the sidenav.

Comment: Are you applying `*ngIf` in `<mat-sidenav>` or on `<mat-sidenav-content>`? And you need to toggle sidenav or hide?

Comment: I'm applying ngif to mat-sidenav. I don't want to toggle but hide the sidenav to show the complete details on page. Toggle is working for me but for this particular route I want to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- app.component.ts --->
constructor(private router: Router){

}

ngOnInit() {

this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
  if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {

    this.getUrl();
  }
});
}

getUrl(){
  this.selectedRoute = this.router.url;
}
```

Now in the `app.component.html` check the route is not equal to the route which you need to hide

`<mat-sidenav *ngIf="selectedRoute !== '/child-route'></mat-sidenav>`

Comment: This worked but I used a property in NGXS store to control the visibility of sideNav. Thanks Chaitanya for your help.